# does azure blob storage use gzip across the wire

Tags: azure, blob

I want to know if there is a benefit to zipping files before sending them to Azure Blob Storage - **strictly for transfer purposes**. Put another way, will pre-zipping files make file transfers any faster when going to/from blob storage? Or does this automatically happen at the transport level by using gzip?

Answer (score 8):

As of 12th August 2015 Azure blob storage (when mounted to the CDN) now supports automatic GZip compression.

> Compression method - Supported compression methods are
>   gzip/deflate/bzip2, a supported method must be set in the
>   Accept-Encoding Request Header.

[Improve performance by compressing files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-improve-performance/)

Comment: Note: The question is about uploading content to the storage account; whilst a CDN would be about serving content from the storage account.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

I'm unsure of what and how I originally did this, but all I can think is that I was looking at the results incorrectly. Everything I can read about azure (from MSDN, to the code itself) is now telling me that Azure does not support gzip for transfer purposes. I do not know under what circumstances I was able to get the following results and am unable to reproduce them now. Needless to say, I'm very disappointed.

---

(THIS ANSWER IS INCORRECT, SEE THE UPDATE ABOVE) The answer is no, there is no benefit for transfer speed purposes to zip a file before sending to blob storage. By turning on Fiddler, you can see that the transport level automatically gzips content across the wire. Screenshots below confirm this:

[image: content encoding from response headers tab]
[image: content size difference]

**Edit 1** - Quick Clarifications for Gaurav

The byte array that comes back in code has a length of 386803, but the network card only saw 23505 bytes go by, because it was gzipped by Azure in the response. I didn't have to do anything for that to happen.

Here is the code I'm using to initiate the request from Blob Storage

```cs
public Byte[] Read(string containerName, string filename)
{
    CheckContainer(containerName);
    Initialize();

    // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
    CloudBlobContainer container = _blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);

    // Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

    byte[] buffer;

    // Save blob contents to a file.
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        blockBlob.DownloadToStream(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

        stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that just by setting `Content-Encoding` property to `GZIP` before uploading will automatically zip the contents before sending?

Comment: no, the content encoding being set to gzip happens by default, you don't have to do anything

Comment: Sorry ... still not getting it (pardon me for being a bit dense :)), I'm really interested in knowing what exactly you did. I would really appreciate if you could explain it step-by-step. Thanks.

Comment: No worries dude. I'm just using the SDK provided by the WindowsAzure.Storage nuget repo. When I have a CloudBlockBlob object and I call "DownloadToStream" on that object, the SDK generates an HTTP request to Azure, and in the HTTP Response from Azure, Azure has set the content-encoding to be gzip. So the stream when it gets back to my code was 386KB, but as far as my network card was concerned only 23KB got transferred over the wire. It isn't a setting that you have to specify anywhere, Azure does it by default (as do most all websites/services). Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. It certainly does. My guess is the storage client library does some magic based on content-encoding and deflates the content. When we built products @ Cerebrata, we implemented REST API and it only sends the compressed bytes. We had to do GZIP decompression on our end. Thanks again for explaining.